Change of variables in $\int_0^{+\infty}\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{u^{q-1} t^{p-1}}{{\rm e}^{t+u}-1}\ {\rm d}t {\rm d}u$
I am reading the paper, "Computation of Polylogarithms" by David C. Wood.
I need help computing the Mellin transform of $\operatorname{Li}_p ({\rm e} ^{-u})$ wrt $u$. This is section 9 of the paper. By the integral representation of the polylogarithm we have
$$\int_0^{+\infty} u^{q-1} \operatorname{Li}_p({\rm e}^{-u} )\ {\rm d}u= \frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\int_0^{+\infty}\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{u^{q-1} t^{p-1}}{{\rm e}^{t+u}-1}\ {\rm d}t {\rm d}u.$$
But now the change of variables $t=rs,u=r(1-s)$ is applied. I need help fixing my mistakes below.

We have ${\rm d} t=r{\rm d} s$ and ${\rm d} u=(1-s){\rm d} r$. Since $t,u$ integrate from $0$ to $+\infty$, and $s=t/r,r=u/(1-s)$ the bounds stay $0$ to $+\infty$. (?) I obtain $$\frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\int _0^{+\infty}s^{p-1} (1-s)^{q}\ {\rm d}s \int _0^{+\infty } \frac{r^{p+q-1}}{{\rm e} ^{r}-1}\ {\rm d} r,$$
which is not correct. The correct expression should be
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\int_0^1 s^{q-1}(1-s)^{p-1}\ {\rm d} s\int _0^{+\infty} \frac{r^{p+q+1}}{{\rm e}^{r}-1}\ {\rm d} r.$$
The bounds for the $s$ integral should be $(0,1)$, and there also is a mismatch of exponents. I know I made a mistake when considering the bounds of integration, but not sure exactly how to continue. Any help is welcome, thank you.

In terms of $t$ and $u$, $s= \frac{t}{t+u}$, which is never greater than $1$.

@RandomVariable. I did just realize that. The issue with the bounds is resolved, thank you.

You  have to use the Jacobian in a variable substitution involving more than one variable.
Give it a new try with that change.
Your method works when the integrand is of the form $f(t)g(u)$ (which your integrand actually is) and the variable substitution is like $r=r(t)$ and $s=s(u)$.

Welcome to MSE. This should be a comment, not an answer.

I would put this answer as a comment.

I am still a few rep-points away from being able of commenting in threads I havent posted in.  Besides, my answear IS short, but I think it gives a full answer to why the first solution didnt work, and a hint hopefully helping the OP to solve the integration himself.

But I can delete the answer if that is desired

I will give it a shot tomorrow.
